# List of list with specific length in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm wondering how can I write a function: `'a list*int -> 'a list*list` that transforms a given list to a list of lists with given maximal length.

For example: `segments( [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9], 2 ) => [ [1;2]; [3;4]; [5;6]; [7;8]; [9] ]`

Comment: It sounds like homework.  It would help if you showed some code you have tried that doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tail-recursive solution:

```
let segments xs n = 
    let rec loop n xs (count, elem) acc = 
        match xs with
        | x::xs' when count < n -> loop n xs' (count+1, x::elem) acc
        | x::xs' -> loop n xs' (1, [x]) ((List.rev elem)::acc)
        | [] -> List.rev ((List.rev elem)::acc) in
    loop n xs (0, []) []
```

The idea is keeping an accumulator for creating current segment and another accumulator for storing a list of segments.

Comment: Your solution is good, however I can see that we can improve. Since the length is given we don't need to use it in the function loop.

As follows:



let segments (t, n) = 
        let rec loop t (count, elem) acc = 
        match t with
        | x::t' when count < n -> loop t' (count+1, x::elem) acc
        | x::t' -> loop t' (1, [x]) ((List.rev elem)::acc)
        | [] -> List.rev ((List.rev elem)::acc) 
 in
    loop t (0, []) []
;;

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial with [`BatList.split_at`](http://thelema.github.com/AAA-batteries/hdoc/BatList.html) :

```
let rec segments list n = 
  try let head, tail = BatList.split_at n list in 
      head :: segments tail n 
  with Invalid_index _ -> [ list ]
```

If you don't have access to Batteries, implementing `split_at` is fairly easy.

Comment: Beware that this solution is not tail-recursive, and is actually eating the stack quite fast because recursion is embedded within try...with constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that using BatList should be used for this.  Sure it's great if you're programming with people used to using those libraries (maybe you are, then please ignore this then!).  But in the "classic" case this is much more naturally done with a simple enough tail recursive function.  (You can fold over append to get something dead trivial, but that doesn't work quite well in practice, and there's a much better accumulator based solution that allows a simple tail call based implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of the **previous correct answer (by pad):**

```
let segments (xs,n) = 
    let rec loop xs (count, elem) acc = 
        match xs with
        | x::xs' when count < n -> loop xs' (count+1, x::elem) acc
        | x::xs' -> loop xs' (1, [x]) ((List.rev elem)::acc)
        | [] -> List.rev ((List.rev elem)::acc) in
    loop xs (0, []) [];;
```